# Android notification alert on windows 10 IOT (UWP) application

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, uwp, windowsiot

I want to develop an UWP application which show notifications (Facebook notifications, incoming call or sms notifications etc) of my android phone.
I want to use Bluetooth for connection of my application and Android phone.
please help me if anyone know how i can do that, many thanks :)

Comment: How does your Android phone send these notifications out, RFCOMM or GATT or others?

Answer (score 0):

You can use project Rome to do this.

Microsoft already has some of these features inside the Cortana app on android.